# call of overloaded function -with inherited class as argument- is ambiguous

Tags: c++

This title has been used many times but after searching around 5-6 examples, I couldn't find anything that matches my problem:

I have a simple inheritance practice.

Class **A** is a base class, classes **B** & **C** inherit from it:

```
class A {

};

class B : public A { public:    int i; };

class C : public A { public:    int j; };
```

And a class P containing overloaded functions like this:

```
class P
{
public:
    void change(B *b)
    {
        b->i =1;
    }

    void change(C *c)
    {
        c->j =1;
    }
};
```

And when I use the functions like the following:

```
int main()
{
    A *b = new B();
    A *c = new C();
    P p;
    p.change(b);
    p.change(c);
    return 0;
}
```

it gives an error saying:

```
inherit2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
inherit2.cpp:37:12: error: call of overloaded ‘change(A*&)’ is ambiguous
inherit2.cpp:37:12: note: candidates are:
inherit2.cpp:21:7: note: void P::change(B*) <near match>
inherit2.cpp:21:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A*’ to ‘B*’
inherit2.cpp:26:7: note: void P::change(C*) <near match>
inherit2.cpp:26:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A*’ to ‘C*’
inherit2.cpp:38:12: error: call of overloaded ‘change(A*&)’ is ambiguous
inherit2.cpp:38:12: note: candidates are:
inherit2.cpp:21:7: note: void P::change(B*) <near match>
inherit2.cpp:21:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A*’ to ‘B*’
inherit2.cpp:26:7: note: void P::change(C*) <near match>
inherit2.cpp:26:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A*’ to ‘C*’
```

I will appreciate if you please help me solve the problem.
rahman

Comment: Last but not least, the pointers and manual memory management here are unnecessary. I realise that this is only a minimal example but this makes the point only stronger: do not use pointers here!

Comment: `P` needs a `change` function that takes an `A*`. This should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Polymorphism is one answer

class A
{
public:
    virtual void set() = 0;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void set() { i = 1; }
private:
    int i;
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    virtual void set() { j = 1; }
private:
    int j;
};

class P
{
public:
    void change(A *a)
    {
        a->set();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *b = new B();
    A *c = new C();
    P p;
    p.change(b);
    p.change(c);
    return 0;
}
```

With polymorphism there is no need for multiple `change` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- Use polymorphism by adding a virtual setter function for `i` and `j`:

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      virtual void set( int ) = 0;
  };

  class B : public A {
  public:
      void set( int value )
      {
          i = value;
      }

  private:
      int i;
  };

  class C : public A {
  public:
      void set( int value )
      {
          j = value;
      }

  private:
      int j;
  };

  class P
  {
  public:
      void change(A * obj)
      {
          obj->set(1);
      }
  };

  int main()
  {
      A *b = new B();
      A *c = new C();
      P p;
      p.change(b);
      p.change(c);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Case the pointer before passing it:

  ```
   A *b = new B();
   A *c = new C();
   P p;
   p.change(static_cast<B*>(b));
   p.change(static_cast<C*>(c));
  ```
- Place the variable into the base class (and get rid of two `change()` functions):

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      int i;
  };

  class B : public A {};

  class C : public A {};
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would tweak your class hierachy to use polymorphism:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void SetVariable(const int value) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void SetVariable(const int value) override { i = value; }
    int i;
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    virtual void SetVariable(const int value) override { j = value; }
    int j;
};

class P
{
public:
    void change(A *a)
    {
        a->SetVariable(1);
    }
};
```

This way you can use pointers to the base class (`A`) without knowing which specific derived type they are.

Answer (score 1):

**Root Cause:**

When you call `change()` the parameter you pass is of the type `A *`, there is no exact match for this function in class `P`. The compiler tries to find the best possible match and it has two choices:

```
void change(B *); 
void change(C *);
```

None of them is a best match because each requires conversion from `A*` to `B*` or `C*`. Not that your classes do not provide for this conversion function and hence compiler reports the error.

**Resolution:**

You tell the compiler exactly which version of the function to chose by using casting.

```
p.change(static_cast<B*>(b));  
p.change(static_cast<C*>(c));
```

In both of above cases you know the actual type of the object being pointed by `A *` and so you can use `static_cast` and guide the compiler to find the best match function.